# How to transform an object to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**I need to transform these objects in Javascript:**

```
const tables = [
      {
      table_name: "Table",
      columns: [
        {
          column_name: 'column_1',
          values: [{value: 'data1_c1', other:25}, {value: 'data2_c1', other:25}]
        },
        {
          column_name: 'column_2',
          values: [{value: 'data1_c2', other:30}, {value: 'data2_c2', other:30}]
        },
        {
          column_name: 'column_3',
          values: [{value: 'data1_c3', other:40}, {value: 'data2_c3', other:40}]
        }
      ]
     }
  ]
```

**to this array**

```
result = [['data1_c1, 'data2_c1'], ['data1_c2, 'data2_c2'], ['data1_c3, 'data2_c3']]
```

Please, I need help with this exercise.

---

**I was trying with this**

```
let result = []

tables.map(table =>(
  table.columns.map(column => (
    column.values.map(value => (
      result.push(value.value)
    ))
  ))
))
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: loop over columns, loop over values, push them into arrarys

Comment: I already edited the question..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have only one item in the `tables` array, you can use

```
const result = tables[0].columns.map((column) => {
  return column.values.map((item) => item.value)
})
```

If you have multiple items, it is a bit more complex:

```
const result = tables.reduce((acc, table) => {
  return acc.concat(
    table.columns.map(column => {
      return column.values.map(item => item.value);
    })
  );
}, []);
```

```js
const tables = [
  {
    table_name: "Table",
    columns: [
      {
        column_name: "column_1",
        values: [
          { value: "data1_c1", other: 25 },
          { value: "data2_c1", other: 25 }
        ]
      },
      {
        column_name: "column_2",
        values: [
          { value: "data1_c2", other: 30 },
          { value: "data2_c2", other:30 }
        ]
      },
      {
        column_name: "column_3",
        values: [
          { value: "data1_c3", other: 40 },
          { value: "data2_c3", other: 40 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const result1 = tables[0].columns.map((column) => {
    return column.values.map((item) => item.value)
})

console.log(result1);

const result2 = tables.reduce((acc, table) => {
    return acc.concat(
      table.columns.map(column => {
        return column.values.map(item => item.value);
      })
    );
  }, []);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple answer

```js
    var result = []
    table[0].columns.forEach(colum => { 
      var cols = []
      colum.values.forEach(valueObj => cols.push(valueObj.value))
      result.push(cols)
    })
```